# (gnupg) Which is the public and which is the private key in this pair?

Tags: gnupg

I need to generate a PGP Public/Private key. I've never done this before. I've read documentation but the examples given do not match what I am seeing on my computer.

I generated the keys with `gnupg`.

I run the command to list the public keys

`gpg --list-keys --keyid-format LONG`

and I get a structure like this.

```
pub   rsa2048/123456789101112A 2000–01-01 [SC] [expires: 2000-01-01]
      ABCD1234ABCD1234ABCD1234ABCD1234ABCD1234

uid                 [ultimate] Firstname Surname <email@gmail.com> 
sub   rsa2048/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO1 2000-01-01 [E] [expires: 2000-01-01]
```

I then run a command to get the secret keys

`gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG`

and I get the same structure

```
sec   rsa2048/123456789101112A 2000–01-01 [SC] [expires: 2000-01-01]
      ABCD1234ABCD1234ABCD1234ABCD1234ABCD1234

uid                 [ultimate] Firstname Surname <email@gmail.com> 
ssb   rsa2048/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO1 2000-01-01 [E] [expires: 2000-01-01]
```

What's different here is the **pub**, **sub**, **sec**, and **ssb** tags, but the content is the exact same.

Which is the public private key in each example that's generated?

Is the sequence in the first line of **pub** or **sec** after the 'rsa2048/' (*123456789101112A*  in the example) the public key? And then the longer sequence in the line below (*ABCD1234ABCD1234ABCD1234ABCD1234ABCD1234* in the example) is the matching private key?

Or is the public key the sequence in the first line of **pub** or **sec** after the 'rsa2048/' (*123456789101112A*  in the example) and then the matching private key is the line of **sub** or **ssb** after the 'rsa2048/' (*ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO1* in the example)?

Comment: [`doc/DETAILS`](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=doc/DETAILS;h=b915f0658e8d809380472e814e8e2aa712cbc247;hb=HEAD) has information about the `--with-colons` format, which contains the same information as the "human readable" version. That might get you on the right track. The numbers after the algorithms are [OpenGPG KeyIDs](https://superuser.com/questions/769452/what-is-a-openpgp-gnupg-key-id). They always reference the public key (even for private keys). **pub** and **sub** are public keys and **sec** and **ssb** are private keys.

Comment: Thanks very much! That was really, really informative!! It leads to another question though; I now know what my `Primary Key` is, and what my `Subkey` is. So I'm assuming that I can use the Primary Key's `KeyId` to encrypt? And the Subkey's `KeyId` to `decrypt`? Except that my SubKey's `Key Capabilities` is just 'e' - encrypt. So I can't decrypt with it?

Comment: If you look closely, the primary key is a pure **S**igning key. That's why it has a subkey for **E**ncryption. You use the **secret** key of a signing key to **sign** a message and the **public** key to verify the signature. For **encryption** keys you use the **public** key for encryption and the matching **private** key for decryption. Gnupg very closely tries to make sure you use separate keys for singing and encrypting.

Comment: This is only a question about gnupg -- not a question about bash (gnupg is not part of bash, it's a separate program not tied to any specific shell), or about terminals (this behavior is the same if your output goes to a terminal, or if it goes to a file, a web browser or anywhere else). I've cleaned up the tagging.

Comment: Also, note that general questions about UNIX tools are better fit for our sister site [unix.se], whereas Stack Overflow is specific to questions about _writing software_.

Answer (score 2):

When you list your keys, `pub` is always your public key, and it could be seen as your "main" key. Associated with it (this "main" key), you have a private key. Any other key (sub, ssb, etc.) are sub-keys that are private.
In order to get the meanings for `sec`, `sub`, `ssb` & `pub`, you can read this post:
[gnupg - What do 'ssb' and 'sec' mean in gpg's output](https://superuser.com/questions/1371088/what-do-ssb-and-sec-mean-in-gpgs-output)

I hope this could solve your 'problem'.